# Code for retrieving the value of a custom field is not working

Tags: jira, scriptrunner-for-jira

I am trying to retrieve the value of a custom field, the custom field looks like this in my Jira issue: 
[image]

I have been able to find the ID by rightclicking on the custom field and choosing the option Inspect Element, Here is the ID:

I wrote the following code to extract the value of the custom field:

[image]

```
  def customField =  ComponentAccessor.getCustomFieldManager().getCustomFieldObject("customfield_10790");// here replace the ID with ID of your custom field.

  def value = (String)issue.getCustomFieldValue(customField); 

                    
   log.warn("MOUNA CAMELIA VALUE "+value )
```

The problem is that I am getting the following value in my log:

**MOUNA CAMELIA VALUE 1000547**

This is a wrong value since it should normally return the value shown below. How to fix this problem?
[image]

The type of the field is a database values selection field so this will not work

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
 def customField =  ComponentAccessor.getCustomFieldManager().getCustomFieldObject("customfield_10790");// here replace the ID with ID of your custom field.
                     def value = issue.getCustomFieldValue(customField) ;   

                    newissue.setCustomFieldValue(customField, value)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use:

```
def value = customField.getValue(issue) as String
```

Comment: The type of the field is a database values selection field so this will not work, I have added a screenshot above in the problem description.